# Ascending/descending array items in javascript

Tags: javascript

**Can someone see the error in my code?**

Complete the method which accepts an array of integers, and returns one of the following:

"yes, ascending" - if the numbers in the array are sorted in an ascending order
"yes, descending" - if the numbers in the array are sorted in a descending order
"no" - otherwise
You can assume the array will always be valid, and there will always be one correct answer.

```
function isSortedAndHow(array) {
  //[1,2,3,4]
  console.log(array)

  //[4,3,2,1]
  let descendarr = array.sort(function(a, b) {return b - a})
  console.log(descendarr)

  //[1,2,3,4]
  let ascendarr = array.sort(function(a, b) {return a - b})
  console.log(ascendarr)

  if(array === descendarr){
    return "yes, descending"
  } else if(array === ascendarr){
    return "yes, ascending"
  } else {
    return "no"
  }
}
```

isSortedAndHow([15, 7, 3, -8])
isSortedAndHow([1,2,3,4])

Comment: looks like a codewars kata

Comment: The `array` has been changed after sorting. Better copy the array first and apply sort into the cloned array.

Comment: And another basic mistake is probably the assumption that _different_ arrays with the same content would be considered identical - they are not. `[1] === [1]` is _false_.

Comment: oh ok so I simply can't compare arrays like this?

Comment: ^^ If you need to check that the contents of two arrays are the same, you can do that with `every`: `array.every((entry, index) => entry === descendarr[index])` (that will be `true` if they have the same contents, `false` if not -- note that that check assumes that `array` won't have objects or arrays in it as elements that would also need to be checked by content rather than identity, since it relies on `===`).

Comment: @CharlieVdb - Right, you can't. Note also Sajeeb's note above about `sort`. It sorts the array in place, it doesn't create a copy of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the array and select a direction test function for checking a previous element with the actual element. If all elements match the condition, you got a sorting.

Otherwise return false.

```js
function isSortedAndHow(array) {
    var fns = {
            ascending: (v, i, a) => !i || a[i - 1] <= v,
            descending: (v, i, a) => !i || a[i - 1] >= v
        },
        direction = array[0] < array[array.length - 1]
            ? 'ascending'
            : 'descending'

    return array.every(fns[direction])
        ? `Yes, ${direction}`
        : 'No';
}

console.log(isSortedAndHow([15, 7, 3, -8]));
console.log(isSortedAndHow([1, 2, 3, 4]));
console.log(isSortedAndHow([1, 2, 0, 4]));
```